# Conditional type/interface property typing

Tags: typescript

I have the following interfaces:

```
interface Movie {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

interface Show {
  title: string;
  ids: {
    trakt: number;
    imdb: string;
    tmdb?: number;
  };
}

interface Props {
  data: Movie | Show;
  inCountdown: boolean;
  mediaType: "movie" | "tv"
}
```

I know that if mediaType is equal to "movie" then `data` is always going to be of a custom type called `Movie`. I want my code to know this without casting or using `as` when using `data`.

I do not want to do something like this, if possible:

```
let docId = "";
if (mediaType === "movie") {
  docId = (data as Movie).id.toString();
}
```

How can I shape this interface so I can use

```
let mediaType = "movie"
let data = {id: 1, title: "Dune"}
let docId = "";

if (mediaType === "movie") {
  docId = data.id.toString();
}
if (mediaType === "tv") {
  docId = data.show.ids.trakt.toString();
}
```

without errors or warnings like `Property 'show' does not exist on type '{ id: number; title: string; }'`?

[Here's a working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&filetype=ts#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsBuwUG8BQyywAJgFzIgCuAtgEbQDchyYwYANhBQM5hSgA5swC%20%20fKEixEKAMoALdAHdkBIm07dkfASGEtSPCmqKsocANZgK1ekxZFgNEnV78hzU62d0A-DdoGKE9kEVFxSWh4JGQABSh0AAceVRYSODA4CgxsFAAfZAVlENAAYXQqcBJlEAo6dHQuOBAQmggSYDgAFQBPRK0AIhosHAHkAoGwTAH8MXwuMGQ2ju6%20lABeZCGRiBmF5HTM5E3cUgoARgAaVnYuCgGAEUrdsX3qhABJEmOtgeYJGDIAAUy06vX6x3Wm22uQGAEpUkR3l8foc4AA6UjosDoWTuPRAuHhYCAkHtMFrSHQqbwxEHdCfb6bNHoniKJSYkg8bHmKzY3H4wSE0RAA).

Comment: This is silly. You can't avoid your second code block - if you can, then I certainly don't know how and I'm very curious as to how if I'm wrong!

Comment: Well, okay, you could - if you wrote a map and addressed it with each element, but that seems like more work than the second code block. Ok I'm done now. I'll wait for answers.

Comment: You can probably do this by making `Props` a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), but right now the code here isn't quite a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [the TypeScript Playground (link)](https://tsplay.dev/WK8RMw).  Could you edit the example code so that it demonstrates what you're seeing without unrelated errors (e.g., `mediaType`, `data`, `TMDB`, `IGDB`, and `Trakt` are not defined; could you either provide typings for them or change them?)

Comment: beat me to it, was just making an [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gNwJbQLxQN5QLaJQBQCc4wAuKAZ2EKQDsBzKAXwG4BYAKFEigHEBDbGkxR6giERLkqNBi2bsu4aABUEUdFmAJJZStTqNWnTnWARCAM34BjaPGQTiYCpk5QoAE37B+5ByiKHnQAwnAArrTAnnAA7rTkAEZwcAA2EPy0QTgQnkj8KsrkAES4jsWcTCYcZhbWdlBquq4Y7l4+fo0I2aERUTHxSSnpmdlCeQVFUMXaFRxVHKZRdbbQAkLNbhwe3r7k6xA9tGGR0XEJUMlpGVlt4-mFkCViQnMLnNzQm+gBTiSuAB8+OJNkCms4KIpODY4LQqFBzFRyN8RLtOlgXn89AByTFQMDObHMAA0UF6pwGF2sqQoEFJ90mTyguPE2OMixqligAApEcAAHQMx5oVDoFlCbEASi2Hg8MLh135qTg9F5ECo-LR-MxukliiYQA)

Comment: @jcalz Added to the example code.

Comment: [There are still unrelated errors](https://tsplay.dev/WJ85lN).  `mediaType` and `data` have not been defined.

Comment:  you are just repeating your self. Why do you need two properties that mean the same. If a === B and B === c, then a===c you’re just been redundant

Comment: Your example confuses me more, unfortunately... do you have a value of type `Props` anywhere?  If so, could you put in your example code?  If not, why are you using it?  I would expect your example to be something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wjJQYw) (with the possible solution in there).  If that represents what you're doing and what your problem is, could you please copy it in as your example code?  If not, could you please edit the code to be a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE? Right now it's still just not demonstrating the problem you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You can just make a union to make sure that illegal state in unrepresentable. In other words - you should make sum type instead of product type.

```js
interface Movie {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

interface Show {
  title: string;
  ids: {
    trakt: number;
    imdb: string;
    tmdb?: number;
  };
}


interface MovieProps {
  data: Movie;
  inCountdown: boolean;
  mediaType: "movie"
}

interface ShowProps {
  data: Show;
  inCountdown: boolean;
  mediaType: "tv"
}

type Props = MovieProps | ShowProps

const Component=(props:Props)=>{
  if(props.mediaType==='tv'){
    props.data // Show
  } else{
    props.data // Movie
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsBuwUG8CwAUMssACYBcyIArgLYBG0A3ESWMGADYRUDOYKKADmrQgF8iRUJFiIUAZQAW6AO7ICxZB269kAoSFFtSZPlU0l2UOAGswVWoxYmSwOmQb9BIsVe0eDAD8jvRMUH7I4mKShFKEMtDwSGhYOAAKUOgADnwaJmRwYHBUGNgQkaAAwug04GRqIFQM6Og8cCCRdBBkwHAAKgCe2XoARHRpEKNEsdLgSfLIymqZOXmWyIXFVMuqlSA1dWANqk3ILW0QHV09fUMjVKNgmNMS8WDDKKu5yAC8qeVvnkAD5LFSqIHxBDoEACZA1OjZGEQcC-AAU2SyuQoQIAlL8AHwbYAwDFYvgAOm6vQGn1%209IA5M8GbiNiRMWsKVs4MgAPS8sFqEziZAQLh8CBs5Ac3Jcoo8-kAnDCmZAA)

Answer (score 0):

The [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) concept in Typescript is different than [Narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type. Here, we need to narrow down the type which we want.

In your example, you also need to check whether any requied key name is present in the data object. This means that the type of data object will get narrowed down to the required type.

You could check keys(or property name) in an object using the `in` operator. See the working example below.

```
let mediaType = "movie"
let data = {id: 1, title: "Dune"}
let docId = "";


function fn(myData: Props['data']){
  if (mediaType === "movie" && 'id' in myData) {
    docId = myData.id.toString(); // this way you can get rid of typecasting
  }
  
  if(mediaType === "tv" && 'ids' in myData){  
    docId = myData.ids.trakt.toString();
  }
}

fn(data);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&filetype=ts#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsBuwUG8BQyywAJgFzIgCuAtgEbQDchyYwYANhBQM5hSgA5swC++fKEixEKAMoALdAHdkBIm07dkfASGEtSPCmqKsocANZgK1ekxZFgNEnV78hzU62d0A-DdoGKE9kEVFxSWh4JGQABSh0AAceVRYSODA4CgxsFAAfZAVlENAAYXQqcBJlEAo6dHQuOBAQmggSYDgAFQBPRK0AIhosHAHkAoGwTAH8MXwuMGQ2ju6+lABeZCGRiBmF5HTM5E3cUgoARgAaVnYuCgGAEUrdsX3qhABJEmOtgeZxGCVBBsdAgZAwEAACkOcHOFHiSR4AG0AOQwlEAXQAlCZgDBkJDlp1ev1jutNttcmMAGTU5Ao0go4hgmHnLGpLzvL4-VkAOlIvLA6Fk7j0kKxITERAMMEJ7WJazJFKmNLpDJIPCZoAOGVhOOlnPQn2+mz5hkF5isguFosE4slswBUJhEqAA)

**Demo:**

```
interface Movie {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}

interface Show {
  title: string;
  ids: {
    trakt: number;
    imdb: string;
    tmdb?: number;
  };
}

interface Props {
  data: Movie | Show;
  inCountdown: boolean;
  mediaType: "movie" | "tv"
}

let mediaType = "movie"
let data = {id: 1, title: "Dune"}
let docId = "";


function fn(data1: Props['data']){
  if (mediaType === "movie" && 'id' in data1) {
    docId = data1.id.toString();
  }
  
  if(mediaType === "tv" && 'ids' in data1){  
    docId = data1.ids.trakt.toString();
  }
}

fn(data);
```